# Loading data from BigQuery into Redis

Tags: python, caching, redis, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to load data from BigQuery into Redis, and after going through their documentation for the last 3 days, I am turning to SO, because I found nothing concrete. So, what would be a good way to load the results of multiple queries, each about a few hundred records, from BigQuery into Redis? Are there any code samples floating around that at least show how to translate a resultset into key-value pairs that are suited to be loaded into Redis? I'd like to use Python to implement this pipeline. Please help. Thanks!

**Edit:** We have a few datasets which we'd like to push to Redis, so that when the user runs a query, it runs against Redis, and not BigQuery. I have a snippet that pulls data from a query into a data frame in Python. I have been unable to find code snippets for loading this data, or even translating this into key-value pairs for consumption into Redis. This is the part I need help with.

Comment: Can you provide more details e.g. what have tried? what documentation are you referring to? what problem are you trying to solve etc.?

Comment: @GrahamPolley: Please see updated question. Thanks!

Comment: According to the updated description, I would suggest to use [redis-py](https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py). You can find docs [here](http://redis-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and a [couple](http://www.bogotobogo.com/python/python_redis_with_python.php) [examples](https://www.fullstackpython.com/blog/install-redis-use-python-3-ubuntu-1604.html).

Answer (score 2):

1. Export the BigQuery table to a GCS bucket as new line delimitated JSON
2. Use a Google Cloud Function triggered by GCS object changes to read the JSON file when it changes
3. Attach a Serverless VPC connector to the Google Cloud Function so it can run a Redis client. It can then write the contends of the file to Redis.

I ended putting the Redis key to use in the BigQuery row, but thats details you can figure out yourself. I wrote a full blog about it here https://www.futurice.com/blog/bigquery-to-memorystore